# Updating or "Refreshing" frames in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

This basically creates all the frames and brings the one we call to the front right?
So as some variables change i want the frames to change accordingly, i tried a few refreshing functions i found while searching in google but none of them worked in this code.

oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

---

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from functools import partial

class MovieTicketapp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.geometry(self, "500x400")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        global user
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, SignUp, Login, EditMovie):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.show_frame(StartPage)
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        global user

        button_signup = ttk.Button(self, text='Sign Up',
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(SignUp)).pack(pady=10, padx=15)
        
        button_EditMovie = ttk.Button(self, text='Edit Movie Details',
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(EditMovie))
        if user == "admin":
            button_EditMovie.pack(pady=10, padx=15)

class SignUp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        button_login = ttk.Button(self, text='Login',
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Login)).pack(pady=10, padx=15)

        button_home = tk.Button(self, text='Home',
                            command=lambda: StartPage.__init__()).pack(pady=10, padx=15)     

class Login(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        def validateLogin(email, password):
            e = email.get() 
            p = password.get()
            
            global user
            user = e
            StartPage.update(self)
            controller.show_frame(StartPage)
            self.pack_forget()

        emailLabel = tk.Label(self, text='Email').pack()
        email = tk.StringVar()
        emailEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable = email).pack()
        passwordLabel = tk.Label(self,text="Password").pack()
        password = tk.StringVar()
        passwordEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=password, show='*').pack()

        validateLogin = partial(validateLogin, email, password)

        loginButton = tk.Button(self, text="Login", command= validateLogin).pack(pady=15, padx=15)
        button_home = tk.Button(self, text='Home',
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage)).pack(pady=10, padx=15)
        

class EditMovie(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        button_home = tk.Button(self, text='Home',
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button_home.pack(pady=10, padx=10)       
        
app = MovieTicketapp()        
app.mainloop()
```

......

Comment: ```MovieTicketapp.update()``` ? well whatever you saved this class too, do variable.update()

Comment: what variables are changing anyway? variables for widgets you can just use ```widgets.configure()```

Comment: The user is changing, depending on the user the ticketdetails, deletetickets frame should change.

Comment: @coderoftheday where do i call it? in the show_frame function? or in the class of the other frames?

Comment: then what ever your frame is called e.g deletetickets_frame , once the user has change its details do  ```deletetickets_frame.update()```

Comment: `
TicketDetails.update(self)
DeleteTickets.update(self)
StartPage.update(self)
`

Used this after the login but it didn't change anything

Comment: Should i add one of the classes so you can understand better?

Comment: yes please, it would be better if you could do this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @coderoftheday I've edited the code

Comment: You should change the type of `user` to `tk.StringVar` and associate this variable to `Label` via `textvariable` option.  Then if you update `user` in `Login` page, the `Label` associated with this variable in other pages will be updated.

Comment: you need to produce a minimal example, the code you've given doesn't run.

Comment: ohhh. wait lemme edit it again

Comment: Done. Also @acw1668 the problem is that the pages arent updating

Comment: code still wont work? do you run code before pasting it?

Comment: Yes. It's working for me